# Tweenmax : is it possible to tween a sprite linestyle?

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, sprite

I'm using TweenMax to make all tweens, fade in a projet. Now my question is : is it possible to tween only linestyle from a Sprite ?

For example, something like that :

```
TweenMax.to ( my_sprite.graphics.lineStyle, 0.5, { tint : 0xFF0000 } );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen, if you wish to alpha the stroke and the fill separately, you need to redraw the shape.

ie. this post - http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=219378

Alternatively, depending on the complexity of the Sprite, you can just make the outline its own Sprite and tween it interdependently.